# Animate switching CollectionViewLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm currently working on a functionality to switch between 2 different `CollectionViewLayouts` for a `UICollectionView`. The switching works perfectly fine, the layouts use the same cell class with different nibs. I would like them to move from one into the other with an animation (grid style to list style and back). Currently I already have some animations integrated by using the Hero transition framework.

What I want to achieve is that the image that is present in both the List & Grid layouts to animate to it's new point of origin, so that the transaction looks smooth.

Is it possible to achieve the behaviour I want with Hero? I have added animations to the cell when selecting which works perfectly fine.

Here is the code I use to switch between the 2 layouts

```swift
isListView = !isListView
setupCollectionViewCellNib(nibName: collectionItem)
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = isListView ? ListLayout(view: view) : GridLayout(view: view)
collectionView.reloadData()
```

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction even when this can't be achieved by using Hero.

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionView` has a `setCollectionViewLayout(_ layout: UICollectionViewLayout, animated: Bool)` function

```
let layout = isListView ? ListLayout(view: view) : GridLayout(view: view)
collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
```

Comment: This doesn't update the nib that is being used to display the cell however. So where it will animate it somewhat the eventual layout is wrong. Even when calling `reloadData()`